# cant get data from show controller to view laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel-5

my PostCOntroller

```
 class PostController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
    $posts = post::all();
    return view('posts.index',['p'=>$posts]);
}

public function show(post $post)
{
    return view('posts.show', ['post'=>$post]);
}
```

master.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href = "/css/bootstrap.css">
   <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="big-info p-5">
   <a href = "{{route('hello.index')}}">Home</a>
   <a href = "{{route('hello.create')}}">Create</a>
  </div>

   <div class="container">
    <center><h1>POST<h1></center>
    @yield('body')

</div>
```

index.blade.php

```
@extends('posts.master')

@section('body')
  @foreach($p as $post)
  <div class="card mt-2">
  <a href = "{{ route('hello.show'),$post->id}}">{{$post->title}}</a>
  </div>
 @endforeach
@endsection
```

show.blade.php

```
@extends('posts.master')

@section('body')

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
     <h3>{{$post->title}}</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="card-body">
     <h3>{{$post->content}}</h3>
  </div>

</div>

@endsection
```

web.php

```
Route::resource('hello','PostController');
```

php artisan route:list

```
 GET|HEAD  | hello              | hello.index   | App\Http\Controllers\PostController@index   | web          |
 POST      | hello              | hello.store App\Http\Controllers\PostController@store   | web          |
 GET|HEAD  | hello/create       | hello.create  | App\Http\Controllers\PostController@create  | web          |
 GET|HEAD  | hello/{hello}      | hello.show    | App\Http\Controllers\PostController@show    | web
```

i think i wrote everything right .. the index page is sending the id of the data from database... the controller is receiving the data in array $post and the show blade should show the data $post->title or $post->content but this is not happening
i think its a silly mistake  but cant figure it out what 
the problem is my show page is not showing data 
please help

#

[image]
adding {{dd($post)}} in index page

```
post {#199 ▼
 #fillable: array:2 [▼
  0 => "title"
  1 => "content"
 ]
#connection: "mysql"
#table: null
#primaryKey: "id"
#keyType: "int"
+incrementing: true
#with: []
#withCount: []
#perPage: 15
+exists: true
+wasRecentlyCreated: false
#attributes: array:5 [▶]
#original: array:5 [▶]
#changes: []
#casts: []
#dates: []
#dateFormat: null
#appends: []
#dispatchesEvents: []
#observables: []
#relations: []
#touches: []
+timestamps: true
#hidden: []
#visible: []
#guarded: array:1 [▼
0 => "*"
]
}
```

adding {{dd($post)}} in show blade

```
post {#195 ▼
 #fillable: array:2 [▶]
 #connection: null
 #table: null
 #primaryKey: "id"
 #keyType: "int"
 +incrementing: true
 #with: []
 #withCount: []
 #perPage: 15
 +exists: false
 +wasRecentlyCreated: false
 #attributes: []
 #original: []
 #changes: []
 #casts: []
 #dates: []
 #dateFormat: null
 #appends: []
 #dispatchesEvents: []
 #observables: []
 #relations: []
 #touches: []
 +timestamps: true
 #hidden: []
 #visible: []
 #guarded: array:1 [▶]
 }
```

Comment: on the top of the page index.php, you should write this `{{dd($post)}}` and show the result

Comment: i have added it in the post please check

Comment: in above result there is no id and title attribute exists.. dd($post) add this line in to controller and check $post has any data or not

Comment: again shows no attribute exists :3 but cant get why

Comment: so, that's mean your form is not send the proper data, again check form and use this line in controller to get input fields `$input = Input::all();` and then dd($input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $hello is the id of a post, your show controller should be:

```
public function show($hello)
{
    $post = Post::find($hello);
    return view('posts.show', ['post'=>$post]);
}
```